# Image generating form on wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I have a PHP form that outputs an image and I have to add this form in the admin panel of my WordPress site, so when I fill the form from the admin panel, the image generated will be on the actual site where other people can see.

It is a car listing site and its a form of car reports. We have the add listing page in the admin panel where the admin can add new listings and that is where I want to insert my form. The add listing page, when the admin is creating a new listing he will also fill the form and thus the image generated will be shown to the end user.

So any ideas how can I accomplish this?

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried so far. Where exactly are you stuck? Currently, this question is too broad and unspecific.

Comment: It seems that you are seraching for some services, stackoverflow is a community to help who have stuck into somthing they are trying. There are several other sites where you can find something like you want.